# Store image on Laravel with Angular

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm trying to store a image on my db with a laravel api as backend and passing it with angular as frontend, in the way that I'm trying it sent the file but when laravel prossesing the "image" is stored as nothing I mean is in white or totally black

In my angular component when a input type file change i start a event

```
fileEvent(e){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    
    if(e.target.files && e.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = e.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
      reader.onload = () => { 
        this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
        this.companyForm.patchValue({
          logo: reader.result
        });
      };
    }
  }
```

My reactive form have this fields

```
companyForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    id: [1],
    tradename: ['', Validators.required],
    rfc: ['', Validators.required],
    sat_name: ['', Validators.required],
    phone: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    zip_code: ['', Validators.required],
    calle: ['', Validators.required],
    numero_exterior: ['', Validators.required],
    numero_interior: [''],
    asentamiento: ['', Validators.required],
    municipio: ['', Validators.required],
    estado: ['', Validators.required],
    ciudad: ['', Validators.required],
    pais: ['', Validators.required],
    logo: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

the way that i send to my API

```
create(token, company): Observable<any>{
    let json = JSON.stringify(company);
    let params = "json=" + json;

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', token);

    return this._http.post(this.url + 'empresa', params, {headers:headers});
}
```

And in my API is like

```
$folderPath = "uploads/company/";
$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $params->logo);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
$company->logo = $file;
```

this is how it store the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a image through a specific folder and store a string local-path to the db which where the image store basically don't store a image through the db just path.

Comment: Sure, I know that, actually in my db I'm just storing the route and the image in a specific folder, but, when the image is storing in the folder I try to see it, and doesn't show something, just a transparent image or an incomplete image